# Writing dispatch function directly inside class react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying out redux for the first time and it is working fine. I have made a counter that can be decreased and increased by one. Below is my code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React from 'react';

function increment() {
   return {
      type: 'INCREMENT'
   }
}
function decrement() {
   return {
      type: 'DECREMENT'
   }
}
function reset() {
   return { type: 'RESET' }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const {counter,increment,decrement,reset} = this.props;
      return (
         <div className = "App">
            <div>{counter}</div>
            <div>
               <button onClick = {increment}>INCREMENT BY 1</button>
            </div>
            <div>
               <button onClick = {decrement}>DECREMENT BY 1</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick = {reset}>RESET</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      counter: state
   };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
      decrement: () => dispatch(decrement()),
      reset: () => dispatch(reset())
   };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

I was just wondering can I modify my code in below way and still get it to work fine:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React from 'react';

function increment() {
   return {
      type: 'INCREMENT'
   }
}
function decrement() {
   return {
      type: 'DECREMENT'
   }
}
function reset() {
   return { type: 'RESET' }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
   constructor(props)
    { super(props);
      this.props.counter=state;}
   render() {
      return (
         <div className = "App">
            <div>{this.props.counter}</div>
            <div>
               <button onClick = {()=>dispatch(increment())}>INCREMENT BY 1</button>
            </div>
            <div>
               <button onClick = {()=>dispatch(decrement())}>DECREMENT BY 1</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick = {()=>dispatch(reset)}>RESET</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default connect()(Counter);
```

I know it may look weird but it is my very first tryout with redux. The second code gives an error that increment is not defind.

Is there any error in the second code that I have written.

Please help me to find out the problem so that I can learn redux better.

Thank You!

Comment: you forgot to read `dispatch` of your `props` first of all. so, `function increment { ... }` is not defined? that seems weird.

Comment: should I write this: ``this.props.dispatch``

Comment: or at the beginning of `render`, before `return` write: `const {dispatch} = this.props;`.

Comment: It is working! But can you explain me how dispatch is being passed as props to the Component. I mean I haven't even written mapDispatchToProps method and passesd it to connect.

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI  Why would you want to do this? The second code assumes what needs to be done on a button click but a presentational component should not decide that and instead have that function passed to it through props. [Here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components) is some documentation that may be useful.

Comment: As I said I am trying out redux for the first time, So I was just trying to do things differently and check if it works!

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI `dispatch` is passed by default to a `connect`'ed component ;) didn't say it is good manner to do so. as @HRM states out good components are pure functions!

Comment: I have one more question. Since that is a little query, so I don't want to ask a seperate question. My question is: How to call getState in a component like above without importing the store directly?